# Combining 2 projects within same workspace

Tags: ios, swift

I have to combine 2 separated projects in same workspace in XCode.
I want to navigate project 1 to project 2 when button click.
Can anyone guide me the best way?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

drag your project in parent project, like any other file and just set proper search Paths in parent build setting for child project, where you pasted the project. then try to build. it should work. If something went wrong, means you are not setting right paths.